# How to make Hierarchical Tree diagram from polygon layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, diagram

I have a polygon layer with 5 hierarchical levels. I added 3 fields to indicate the level and the group. The hierarchy is also shown spatially, ie. a big polygon contains the other lower level polygons that are contained in that group.

What is the best tool to create diagram of hierarchical tree from the data?

I don't have license for [Schematics](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/schematics) or [Visio](https://products.office.com/en-us/visio/flowchart-software).  I have Excel 2007.
[image: polygons]
[image]

Comment: ArcGIS Schematics Extension looks like it will create diagrams from shapefiles.  You may want to take a look at that: http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/schematics

Answer (score 1):

There is a free program called [**yEd**](http://www.yworks.com/en/products/yfiles/yed/) which can create flowcharts and hierarchical diagrams.  One of the import formats is Excel.  You could export your layer as an Excel File using the **[Table To Excel](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000054000000)** tool.

I spent about five minutes trying to import a hierarchical file that I created with three levels with mediocre success.  I didn't read the help though.  You might also want to try exporting your data as some form of XML which yEd can also read.